# How can I add \widearcarrow{} from kpfonts without using this package?

Tags: kpfonts

I want to add `\widearcarrow`  (or same command) from `kpfonts` without using this package because I already used other font.
I tried to use `\usefont` and `\symbol` command but I dont know how to use them.
Thank for your help!

[image: Using red box's symbol]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/124577).

Comment: But I dont know how to insert that symbol which has parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have all the data. Just put them together: the symbol should point to the first slot in the series and TeX will provide the one with the right width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{kplargesymbols}{OMX}{jkp}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widearc}{\mathalpha}{kplargesymbols}{"86}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widearcarrow}{\mathalpha}{kplargesymbols}{"8C}

\begin{document}

$\widearcarrow{A}$
$\widearcarrow{AA}$
$\widearcarrow{AAA}$
$\widearcarrow{AAAA}$

$\widearc{A}$
$\widearc{AA}$
$\widearc{AAA}$
$\widearc{AAAA}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why you not declare fontencoding and fontsubstitution be like:

`\makeatletter`
`\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}`
`\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}`
`\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}`
`\DeclareMathSymbol{\sml} {\mathbin}{operators}{"EF}`
`\makeatother`

Comment: @MinhHoàng The OMX encoding is predefined and the `.fd` file for `jkp` already has the necessary information.