# DeclareMathOperator and widearcarrow with kpfonts

Tags: math-operators, kpfonts

The title says it all, I am using the package kpfonts and I would like to declare a math operator that has a widearc on top. However, when I compile I don't get any arc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{
  kpfonts
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\dSing}{\widearcarrow{Sing}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sSing}{\widehat{Sing}}
\begin{document}    
\[\dSing(X) \quad \widearcarrow{Sing}\quad\sSing(A)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the command widehat is working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks @Mico and thanks everybody for your answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, math accents from family 3 don't work in `\operatorname`.

You can use a lower level interface:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\dSing}{%
  \mathop{\widearcarrow{\mathrm{Sing}}}\nolimits
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sSing}{\widehat{Sing}}

\begin{document}

\[
\dSing(X) \quad \widearcarrow{Sing} \quad \sSing(A)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Replace `\newcommand` instead of `\DeclareMathOperator` and your code works perfectly.

For the differences between `\newcommand`and `\DeclareMathOperator` I suggest to see this link: [newcommand vs. DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand{\dSing}{\widearcarrow{\mathrm{Sing}}}
\newcommand{\sSing}{\widehat{\mathrm{Sing}}}
\begin{document}    
\[\dSing(X) \quad \widearcarrow{Sing}\quad\sSing(A)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer! One tweak: if you redefine the operator font or `\mathrm`, so that they’re no longer the same, you can replace `\mathrm{Sing}` with `\operatorname{Sing}`.

Comment: @Davislor I thank you and all of you from the bottom of my heart. I've only had luck :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\widearcarrow{\text{#1}}}
\def\dSing{\d{Sing}}
```

Don't know why it works this way, but it does. May be a feature of the definition of `widearcarrow` in the [package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369679/how-can-i-add-widearcarrow-from-kpfonts-without-using-this-package).